# Is it fine to add future callback for each publish?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have abstracted the message schema (Event). There are different implementations of Event and they are published as a message. They also implement their own future callback methods.

```
    @Async
    @Override
    public void sendAsyncEvent(Event event) {
        try {
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, Event>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, event);
            future.addCallback(event.getFutureCallback());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
        }
    }
```

My question, is it fine to add callback for each event message? I'm afraid that previously added callbacks will remain and not removed. I don't want them to be stacked in the memory. Just not sure if the above usage is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's fine; the callback (and future, and event) will eventually be garbage collected when there are no more references to them.